# How do I work with queryParams while future-proofing my Ember application?

Tags: ember.js

I am attempting to follow the guide located at https://gist.github.com/samselikoff/1d7300ce59d216fdaf97 to future proof my Ember application for version 2.0.

In the document, samselikoff states we should be leaving our controllers blank and setting them up utilizing the `setupController` method of the route, basically setting all of our properties on the "attrs" hash.

How can we set and work with our query parameters when following this advice?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, it looks like queryParams can be accessed via the transition on setupController like so:

```
setupController: function(controller, model, transition) {
  controller.set('attrs.pageNum', transition.queryParams.pageNum);
}
```